# Operational analytic real time reporting

Tags: sql-server, in-memory, columnstore, sql-server-2016

I truly understand that it is quite too early to ask this question but I have a requirement similar to that I would like to create a `POC` on that.

How can I implement operational analytic on `SQL Server 2016`? I know that I have create `columnstore index` on In-Memory table. But I am unsure about reporting package. How can I implement real time reporting `([demo][1])`? 
Can I implement it on `SSRS`? or do I need any other reporting pack (may be something related to azure)

[Reference](https://youtu.be/8sVoHD0roJ4?t=736)

Comment: Have you tried PowerBI.com?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options in SQL Server 2016:
 - disk-based Nonclustered Columnstore Index (updatable)
 - memory-optimised Clustered Columnstore Index (updatable, but has a lot of limitations and different syntax for the maintenance)

As for the reporting, you can keep on using T-SQL to access the data, and so you can use your old SSRS reports or create new SSRS reports - as long as the T-SQL is functioning, everything is fine. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was actually looking for a real time reports. I don't think Microsoft has any solution yet other than operational analytics on azure.